# View querying a shared server takes 44 mins to run, any ideas to make it faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, view

I have this (anonymised) view:

```
CREATE view <View Name>
AS

WITH <common_table_expression 1> AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        Column1 = LEFT(Column2, 36), 
        Column3, 
        Column4
    FROM [Shared Server].Database.dbo.Table
    WHERE Column5 in (99, 100, 101, 102, 107) 
        AND (Column3 > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
        OR Column4 = 'Active')
),
<common_table_expression2> AS (
    SELECT
        Column6 = COALESCE(columna, columnb, columnc, columnd, columne, columnf, columng),
        Column7 = COALESCE(columnh, columni, columnj, columnk, columnl, columnm, columnn),
        Column8,
        r.Column9,
        r.Column10,
        p.Column3,
        p.Column4,
        Column11 = coalesce (columno, columnp),
        Column12 = coalesce(columnq, cef.columnr, ef.columns, ic.columnt, ngs.columnu, oef.columnv, sfc.columnw)
    FROM Table1 r
        INNER JOIN Table2 p ON r.Column13 = p.Column14
        LEFT JOIN Table3 q ON r.Column15 = q.Column16
        left join Table4 a on a.Column17 = Column18
        left join Table5 cef on cef.Column19 = Column20
        left join Table6 ef on ef.Column21 = Column22
        left join Table7 ic on ic.Column23 = Column24
        left join Table8 ngs on ngs.Column25 = Column26
        left join Table9 oef on oef.Column27 = Column28
        left join Table10 sfc on sfc.Column29 = Column30
    WHERE q.Column31 IS NULL 
        OR q.Column31 = 'BA6B87E5-B3DF-E111-B758-00155D650A0F' 
),
<common_table_expression3> AS ( 
    SELECT Column6, today = COUNT(0)
    FROM <common_table_expression2>
    WHERE Column3 BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
        AND Column4 = 'Inactive'
    GROUP BY Column6
),
<common_table_expression4> AS ( 
    SELECT 
        r.Column12,
        r.Column6,
        r.Column7,
        Column32 = MAX(today), 
        Column33 = SUM(CASE WHEN Column9 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 
        Column34 = SUM(CASE WHEN Column9 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
        Column11 = MAX(Column11),
        Column3 = MAX(Column3)

    FROM <common_table_expression2> r
        INNER JOIN <common_table_expression3> d on r.Column6 = d.Column6
    GROUP BY r.Column6, r.Column7, r.Column12
)


SELECT
    Column12,
    Column36 = 'uniquecode',
    Column37 = 1,
    Column11 = CONVERT(Date, Column11),
    Column3

FROM <common_table_expression4>
UNION ALL

SELECT
    Column12,
    Column36 = 'uniquecode2',
    Column37 =  CASE active WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE ROUND((CAST(inactive AS DECIMAL)/CAST(active + resigned AS DECIMAL)), 2) END,
    Column11 = CONVERT(Date, Column11),
    Column3
FROM <common_table_expression4>




GO
```

However, it takes 44 mins to run, please can someone help me! It is looking across a shared server which seems to be the issue but I'm not sure how to write it differently to make it quicker. I wondered if tabled functions might work?

The Estimated Execution plan states: "Query 1: Query Cost (relative to batch): 50% USE [Database1]

USE DATABASE Cost: 0%

Query 2: Query Cost (relative to batch): 50%
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[VIEW NAME]    Script Date: 07/21/2015 10:57:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET ON/OFF Cost: 0%

Apologies for my poor explanation, let me know if any other info is required.

Thanks!

Comment: [Some rules of thumb . . .](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49568/1064). Edit your question, and paste the execution plan and indexes. Edit your tags, and tag the dbms you're using (PostgreSQL, DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have added a few things :)

Comment: It looks like the CTE 1 isn't even being used for anything. If the remote server is the reason, can you fetch the data into a temp. table first and use that in your SQL?

Comment: I did think of that but I didn't think you could write temp. tables in views?

Comment: The execution plan of the CREATE VIEW script doesn't help.  The execution plan of a SELECT from the view might help.